# Item is not deleting from the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to delete the item but cant get why the item is not removing from the array its in last line on delete item function but the item is not getting delete from data array i splice the array but thats also not work for me if there is any better solution plz help me out

Its in deleteitem function

```js
  //Constructor for student form
var studentForm = function(iD,name,city,college,course,age){
    this.id = iD;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.college = college;
    this.course = course;
    this.age = age;
}
//all data store here as object
var data = [];

//function to submit and display form
var submitForm = function(){

    //getInput data from the field
    var getInput = {
        name:document.querySelector('.name').value,
        city:document.querySelector('.city').value,
        college:document.querySelector('.college').value,
        course:document.querySelector('.course').value,
        age:document.querySelector('.age').value,
    }
    
    //store the data which you get previous to use that
    var input = getInput;
    //Create a new id
    var ID;
    if(data.length > 0){
       ID = data[data.length - 1].id +1;
    }else{
        ID =1;
    }
    //Use the constructor and make a new data
    var newForm = new studentForm(ID,input.name,input.city,input.college,input.course,input.age);
    //Add the student data into the ds
    data.push(newForm);
    //Display the data in the Document
    //html line to display data of object
    var html = '<tr id="id-%roll%"><td>%id%</td><td class="tname">%name%</td><td class="tcity">%city%</td><td class="tcollege">%college%</td><td class="tcourse">%course%</td><td class="tage">%age%</td><td><button class="delbtn">Delete</button></td></tr>';        
    //Replace the placeHOlder With actual data
    var newHtml = html;
    //newHtml = "<td class=\"id-%id%\">%id%</td>".replace(/%id%/g, ID)
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%roll%',ID);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%id%',ID);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%name%',input.name);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%city%',input.city);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%college%',input.college);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%course%',input.course);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%age%',input.age);
    //Get the element which after you wants to print the data
    document.querySelector('.tablemain').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newHtml);
    //Clearint the fields
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.name' + ', ' + '.city' + ', ' + '.college' + ', ' + '.course' + ', ' + '.age');
   //Convert it into array
    var fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);
    //Loopthrough all fields to clear the fields
    fieldsArr.forEach(function(current,index,array){current.value = '';});
    fieldsArr[0].focus();
    
    //Deleting element
    // parent element class = table id = id delete button class =delbtn
    
    
    
    console.log(newForm);
    return newForm;
}
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click',submitForm);
    
    //Delete section
    //Deleting element
    // parent element class = table id = id delete button class =delbtn
document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click',delItem);
    function delItem(e){
        var iTemId,splitID;
       iTemId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        if(iTemId){
       splitID = iTemId.split('-');
      var ElementID = parseInt(splitID[1]);
            var deleteItem = function(id){
             var ids = data.map(function(cur){
                return cur.id; 
             });
             var index = ids.indexOf(id);
                if(index !== -1){
                 data.slice(index,1);   
                }
            };
            deleteItem(ElementID);
        };
    };
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="city" class="city">
    <input type="text" placeholder="college" class="college">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Course" class="course">
    <input type="number" placeholder="age" class="age">
    <button class="btn" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="table">
    <table class="tablemain">
<tr class="table-heading"><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>College</th><th>Course</th><th>Age</th><th>Delete</th></tr>      
   </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Its in the bottom of the code

Comment: You need to use `splice` instead of `slice`. More importantly, you need to redraw table after you change your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splice and Slice both are JavaScript Array functions. The `splice()` method returns the removed item(s) in an array while mutating the original array and `slice()` method returns the selected element(s) in an array, as a new array object without mutating the original array.

What you have used here is `slice` instead of `splice`. If you want to use `slice`, return the resulting array or replace `slice` with `splice`

```js
if(index !== -1){
   data.splice(index,1);   
}

// Or
if(index !== -1){
   const newData = data.slice(index,1);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future questions, you'll get more responses if you can simplify  your question as much as possible. The code you posted is a little tough to grok.

That being said, I think the issue is here `data.slice(index,1);`. `Array.prototype.slice` does not mutate the original array. It returns a new array. For this reason, sometimes folks use it to create copies of an array to avoid mutation with something like `const arrCopy = originalArr.slice();`.

I think you are looking for the array `splice` method.

Hope this gets you closer. Where is `data` declared? I see you're doing all sorts of things to it and treating as a global var but not sure where you declare it.

Comment: Yeah thanks its working thanks for your guidence actually i am begginer i will remind what you say thanks for helping man

Comment: anytime. Keep at it. Everyone has to start somewhere. Getting good is more about asking lots of questions and putting in the time than anything else! good luck

Answer (score 0):

I just modified `delItem` function

- delete table row
- set index to -1 (because array starts from 0)

```js
 //Constructor for student form
var studentForm = function(iD,name,city,college,course,age){
    this.id = iD;
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
    this.college = college;
    this.course = course;
    this.age = age;
}
//all data store here as object
var data = [];

//function to submit and display form
var submitForm = function(){

    //getInput data from the field
    var getInput = {
        name:document.querySelector('.name').value,
        city:document.querySelector('.city').value,
        college:document.querySelector('.college').value,
        course:document.querySelector('.course').value,
        age:document.querySelector('.age').value,
    }
    
    //store the data which you get previous to use that
    var input = getInput;
    //Create a new id
    var ID;
    if(data.length > 0){
       ID = data[data.length - 1].id +1;
    }else{
        ID =1;
    }
    //Use the constructor and make a new data
    var newForm = new studentForm(ID,input.name,input.city,input.college,input.course,input.age);
    //Add the student data into the ds
    data.push(newForm);
    //Display the data in the Document
    //html line to display data of object
    var html = '<tr id="id-%roll%"><td>%id%</td><td class="tname">%name%</td><td class="tcity">%city%</td><td class="tcollege">%college%</td><td class="tcourse">%course%</td><td class="tage">%age%</td><td><button class="delbtn">Delete</button></td></tr>';        
    //Replace the placeHOlder With actual data
    var newHtml = html;
    //newHtml = "<td class=\"id-%id%\">%id%</td>".replace(/%id%/g, ID)
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%roll%',ID);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%id%',ID);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%name%',input.name);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%city%',input.city);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%college%',input.college);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%course%',input.course);
    newHtml = newHtml.replace('%age%',input.age);
    //Get the element which after you wants to print the data
    document.querySelector('.tablemain').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',newHtml);
    //Clearint the fields
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll('.name' + ', ' + '.city' + ', ' + '.college' + ', ' + '.course' + ', ' + '.age');
   //Convert it into array
    var fieldsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fields);
    //Loopthrough all fields to clear the fields
    fieldsArr.forEach(function(current,index,array){current.value = '';});
    fieldsArr[0].focus();
    
    //Deleting element
    // parent element class = table id = id delete button class =delbtn
    
    
    
    console.log(newForm);
    return newForm;
}
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click',submitForm);
    
    //Delete section
    //Deleting element
    // parent element class = table id = id delete button class =delbtn
document.querySelector('.table').addEventListener('click',delItem);
    function delItem(e){
    // Delete table row
    document.getElementById(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id).remove();
        var iTemId,splitID;
       iTemId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        if(iTemId){
       splitID = iTemId.split('-');
      var ElementID = parseInt(splitID[1]);
            var deleteItem = function(id){
             var ids = data.map(function(cur){
                return cur.id; 
             });
             var index = ids.indexOf(id);
                if(index !== -1){
                 // delete array in data (array start with 0)
                 data = data.slice(index-1,1);   
                }
            };
            deleteItem(ElementID);
        };
    };
```

```html
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" class="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="city" class="city">
    <input type="text" placeholder="college" class="college">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Course" class="course">
    <input type="number" placeholder="age" class="age">
    <button class="btn" value="submit">Submit</button>
    <div class="table">
    <table class="tablemain">
<tr class="table-heading"><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>College</th><th>Course</th><th>Age</th><th>Delete</th></tr>      
   </table>
    </div>
```